# How to use Jquery to assign an event handler to all tags of a certain class

Tags: jquery, event-handling, pagination, onclick

Let's say I have a list of 15 anchor tags (for pagination of an image gallery) at the bottom of my page that looks like this

```
<a href"#" class="paginate" name="1">1</a>
<a href"#" class="paginate" name="2">2</a>
<a href"#" class="paginate" name="...">...</a>
<a href"#" class="paginate" name="15">15</a>
```

During page initialization I want to get all of those anchor tags with class name `"paginate"` and assign the same onclick event handler function.

This function will take the `name` attribute of the clicked link as a parameter so that I can write some logic to determine which images to load in the gallery based on which link was clicked.

How can I do this in Jquery? Can someone give an example using the .bind() function or something similar that is appropriate to this situation?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
$('a.paginate') // select all a elements with the paginate class
    .click(function() { // and attach a click handler function to each
        this.name; // the element that was clicked can be accessed with the this keyword
                   // and its name property can be found with this.name
    });
```

Note, however, that the `name` attribute is not the best place to store this data, because, semantically, it's not a name.  If I were you, I'd use a custom `data-page` attribute instead.  This means you can use jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) functionality:

```
<a href"#" class="paginate" data-page="1">1</a>
```

Which would allow the jQuery:

```
$('a.paginate') 
    .click(function() { 
        var page = $(this).data('page');
    });
```

Comment: Ah, exactly what I was looking for! I will look into a custom data-page attribute, never seen that before. 

Thanks! Very fast and clear response!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.paginate').click(function() {
     var name = $(this).attr('name');

    // --- code here ----
});
```

hope it helps..